# How to passthrough GPU/PCI-e with QEMU 7.0 on macOS host to Windows guest

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, qemu

I have a PC with a powerful Nvidia GPU that is used for mining only through a simple Windows application. For my love in Hackintosh, I installed a new SATA drive and installed macOS Monterey 12.4 and it's now running smoothly through the integrated GPU (Intel UHD Graphics 630). Since Nvidia is not compatible with Monterey, and since I use Windows for running the mining app only, I thought to use QEMU to create a Windows VM with the original hard drive and passthrough Nvidia GPU. That however never worked, as there's no kexts/drivers loaded for Nvidia. I don't know the command for passthrough PCIe device.

Here's how the `boot-windows.sh` file looks like:

```
DISK="/dev/disk1"
OVMFDIR="usr/share/edk2/ovmf" #for enabling secure EFI boot
diskutil umountDisk "$DISK" #to make sure it's forcibly unmounted
MY_OPTIONS="+ssse3,+sse4.2,+popcnt,+avx,+aes,+xsave,+xsaveopt,check"
ALLOCATED_RAM="8G" #GB

args=(
  -m "$ALLOCATED_RAM"
  -vga virtio
  -display cocoa
  -usb
  -device usb-tablet
  -smp 4,cores=4,sockets=2
  -drive if=ide,index=2,file="$DISK",format=raw
  -machine type=q35
  -accel hvf
  #-drive file=/Volumes/OSes/win/21H1.iso,media=cdrom,index=0
  #-drive file=virtio-win-0.1.208.iso,media=cdrom
  -nic user,model=virtio
  -rtc base=localtime,clock=host
  -cpu Nehalem,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time 
  -device intel-hda
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file="$OVMFDIR"/OVMF_CODE.fd
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file="$OVMFDIR"/OVMF_VARS.fd
  -boot c
)

qemu-system-x86_64 "${args[@]}"
```

From the System Information I can use the `VendorID` and `ProductID` to passthrough any USB device, which I used with the WiFi adapter.

[image]

using the below command in the args

`-device usb-host,vendorid=0x2357,productid=0x0109`

Since the Nvidia GPU is a PCIe (not USB), and since it has no kexts loaded, so there's no `ProductID` identified for it, I can't use the same `usb-host` arg.

[image]

My question is **how to passthrough the PCIe GPU to Windows guest**?

This is how the final setup looks like with Windows 11 guest running on the `virtio` standard vga.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, macOS does not have a direct equivalent to Linux's `vfio` kernel driver and user space API, which Qemu consumes to make PCI(e) passthrough work on Linux.

[It would be possible to implement this functionality as a kext](https://github.com/machyve/xhyve/issues/108#issuecomment-1126866242), but Apple is gradually phasing out kexts in recent macOS versions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the quality detailed comments on GitHub, it seems impossible on macOS 12+, but I think it's doable on Big Sur, correct?

Comment: It’s technically possible in both but might require SIP to be turned off.

Comment: I have SIP already turned off. Do you have a guide to follow on that?

Comment: The comments in that GitHub issue go into a lot of detail, and should be enough to set you on the right track if you’re proficient at systems/kernel programming. It’s probably aiming rather high if not.